PyQt QGraphicsScene Render Scene As Video Format
I'm trying to allow the user to export the scene as an mp4 (video format), the items of the scene consists of QGraphicsVideoItem and multiple QGraphicsTextItem, I need to export the scene as it will allow the user to save the video with the text items. I've found one of the ways to do this but the issue is that it will take hours for a simple 5 seconds videos as it saves every image to a byte to create a video, every image is a millisecond. If I change from millisecond to seconds it could speed up but the video will not look as smooth, is there a more efficient way of doing this, without it taking so long?
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtSvgWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QGraphicsVideoItem
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QAudioOutput, QMediaMetaData 

import subprocess

import sys

class ExportVideo(QThread):
    def __init__(self, video_item, video_player, graphics_scene, graphics_view):
        super().__init__()
        self.video_item = video_item
        self.video_player = video_player
        self.graphics_scene = graphics_scene
        self.graphics_view = graphics_view
    
    def run(self):
        self.video_player.pause()
        duration = self.video_player.duration()
        meta = self.video_player.metaData()


        # Prepare a pipe for ffmpeg to write to
        ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-r', '1000', '-i', '-', '-c:v', 'libx265', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', 'output.mp4'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

        for duration in range(0, duration):
            self.video_player.setPosition(duration)

            # Add logic to render the frame here
            print("Exporting frame:", duration) 

            image = QImage(self.graphics_scene.sceneRect().size().toSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
            painter = QPainter(image)
            self.graphics_scene.render(painter)
            painter.end()

            # Convert QImage to bytes
            byte_array = QByteArray()
            buffer = QBuffer(byte_array)
            buffer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
            image.save(buffer, 'JPEG')

            # Write image bytes to ffmpeg process
            ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(byte_array.data())

        # Close the pipe to signal ffmpeg that all frames have been processed
        ffmpeg_process.stdin.close()
        ffmpeg_process.wait()


class PyVideoPlayer(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.text_data = []

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer()
        self.audioOutput = QAudioOutput()

        self.graphics_view = QGraphicsView()
        self.graphic_scene = QGraphicsScene()

        self.graphics_view.setScene(self.graphic_scene)
        self.graphic_scene.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.black)
        self.graphics_view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.graphics_view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.video_item = QGraphicsVideoItem()
        self.graphic_scene.addItem(self.video_item)
        self.save_video = QPushButton()
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.graphics_view, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(self.save_video)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Slots Section
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.video_item)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.changeVideoPosition)
        self.save_video.clicked.connect(self.saveVideo)

    def setMedia(self, fileName):
        self.mediaPlayer.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName))
        self.mediaPlayer.setAudioOutput(self.audioOutput)
        self.play()
        self.video_item.setSize(self.mediaPlayer.videoSink().videoSize())

        self.text_item = QGraphicsTextItem()
        self.text_item.setPlainText("Test Dummy")
        self.text_item.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.white)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(90)  
        self.text_item.setFont(font)
        self.text_item.setPos(self.graphic_scene.sceneRect().x() + self.text_item.boundingRect().width(), self.graphic_scene.sceneRect().center().y() - self.text_item.boundingRect().height())
        self.graphic_scene.addItem(self.text_item)
        self.text_data.append("Test Dummy")

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState() == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def changeVideoPosition(self, duration):
        if duration > 1000 and self.text_item.isVisible():
            print("Hide Text")
            self.text_item.hide()

    def resize_graphic_scene(self):
        self.graphics_view.fitInView(self.graphic_scene.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.resize_graphic_scene()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.resize_graphic_scene()

    def saveVideo(self):
        self.videoExport = ExportVideo(self.video_item, self.mediaPlayer, self.graphic_scene, self.graphics_view)
        self.videoExport.start()

    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PyVideoPlayer()
    window.setMedia("example.mp4")
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)  # Set the window size
    window.setWindowTitle("QGraphicsView Example")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



EDIT: Changed from PNG to JPEG, it speeds up the image.save, I also get this issue: Assertion fctx->async_lock failed at C:/ffmpeg-n6.0/libavcodec/pthread_frame.c:155. I think it must have to do with setting the video player position.


I've noticed that the image.save(buffer, 'PNG') is the process that takes longer and slows the whole process, if there is a more efficient way of getting the image Byte Arrays it should be possible to speed up video creation, I think.

Is the text fixed for the duration?

Both approaches are completely inefficient. If the user does nothing for a few seconds (or even minutes/hours), the processing will store thousands of identical images, unnecessarily occupying memory and CPU. A more appropriate concept could keep a data pair using the (monotonic) timestamp and the related rendered content, updated along with the QGraphicsScene.changed signal. Since you don't need real-time rendering, you can then finalize the output with proper ffmpeg commands, using the different "keyframes" based on their timestamps.

Could you show me an example of the improvements you are suggesting, the text won't be fixed as they will have a start end end time depending on the video time, and later on will have animations.

I don't know how to handle it on the Qt end, but the most efficient approach is to take snapshots of only the text objects (individually) as images, and superimpose them to the video in FFmpeg with its filtergraph. This way you won't be wasting time capturing video frames. I'll put an answer together later if interested in this approach.

One more Q. Do you care to match the format of the text (font, size, etc.) to what's on the screen? If not, you can just use drawtext filter.

Yeah, the user will be able to change the text format and there will be various text.

@kesh, I've tried doing the way that you are suggesting before but I kept getting an error and reverted back to capturing the video and text. The way you are suggesting would probably be more efficient, I'm guessing.

@Alex Another thing, which is of extreme importance: UI elements are not thread safe. Not only they cannot be created or "written" (changing their properties) from separate threads, but accessing them in "read mode" is still unsafe and completely unreliable. Furthermore, video playback can be very demanding, meaning that trying to capture the whole content of the scene may cause delays not only to the recording, but to the playback too. Python doesn't really play well with real-time high demanding tasks, so you only have two options: 1. if you don't need perfectly smooth recording, then »

@Alex » just use a combination of QTimer and the aforementioned changed signal as optimizations; this will still cause potential lags in playback of the app while recording if the CPU can't keep up; 2. if you need safer (still depending on the CPU) smooth playback and recording, you have to switch to multiprocessing or a completely different language. In any case, what explained above remains: 1. continuous recording makes no sense; 2. you shall not use threading to render a widget.

I think I might have a better way to export the video as the user won't be able to change the video only the text that is displayed, I'm trying to make it so that It grabs each text format and start / end times, which it will use this information to create the text over the video by using drawtext from ffmpeg. There will probably be customization limitations but I think this will be more efficient than using the render function from the scene and won't be as demanding on the CPU.

Can you just save the text graphic object as a PNG with transparent background? I think that would be the best of both worlds

I've tried that and since there is a video on the background it exports the text and the video, as the only way to render that I'm aware is with scene.render and this renders anything that is on the bounds that you've requested to render, so if there is anything behind the text it also renders that. I'm trying to make the changes that musicamante suggested and if I'm unable I might have to stick with your suggestion or writing text directly to the video.

@musicamante the video playing and exporting the video doesn't have to happen at the same time, if that's what you mean by " playback and recording". At the moment I have the thread changing the video position so the text knows when to no longer show and to play the next part of the video. However, if its not required to set the video position to capture the video frame and the text could you let me know how, thanks

Sorry, from your initial question it seemed like you wanted to do a "screen cast" of the scene. In reality, you just want to add elements to the video, which means that rendering the QGraphicsScene is not only pointless, but completely wrong. You should store logical object data you want to draw over (item geometries, contents, timeline appearance, etc.) and eventually export that using the source video, not the video graphics item.

The fix I found doesn't use PyQt for the main exporting of the video but rather its all FFMPEG. I knew FFMPEG didn't support Rich Text Format (RTF) so I started to look at other possible ways to overcome this issue, I found out you could use a file format called Advanced SubStation Alpha (.ASS) which lets you control anything to do with the text, such as font, size, color, start / end times and more.
When using .ASS you need to make sure you are formatting the .ASS file correctly otherwise FFMPEG might not write the subtitles how you want them. You also need the text you want to display in the video as a html which can be done by using pyqt text.toHtml().
When you've got your text html version location path, you will also need the stroke size / color and start / end of your text, you can also edit it to include the text position. You will have to call the function with your original video.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import subprocess, sys
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

class videoExport(QThread):
    def __init__(self, text_and_stroke, video_location):
        super().__init__()
        self.text_and_stroke = text_and_stroke
        self.video_location = video_location

    def run(self):
        dialogues = []

        for html_file_path, pos_x, pos_y, stroke_size, stroke_color, start, end in self.text_and_stroke:
            with open(html_file_path, 'r') as file:
                html_content = file.read()
                
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
            body_tag = soup.find('body')


            if body_tag:
                self.styles_attributes = self.retrieve_text_style(body_tag.get('style'))
                text_style = self.text_styles(soup, stroke_size, stroke_color)

                self.styles_attributes = ",".join(self.styles_attributes)
                text_style = "".join(text_style)

                new_dialogue = f"""Dialogue: {start},{end},Default,{{\pos({pos_x},{pos_y})}}{text_style}"""
                dialogues.append(new_dialogue)

            file.close()


        create_ass_file = f"""[Script Info]
Title: Video Subtitles
ScriptType: v4.00+
Collisions: Normal
PlayDepth: 0

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BorderStyle, Encoding
Style: Default, {self.styles_attributes},&HFFB0B0,&HFFFF00,&H998877,0,0
Style: Background, {self.styles_attributes},&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,3,0

[Events]
Format: Start, End, Style, Text
"""
        
        for dialogue in dialogues:
            create_ass_file += f"{dialogue}\n"

        with open("new_ass.ass", 'w') as file:
            file.write(create_ass_file)

        file.close()

        self.add_subtitle_to_video(self.video_location, "new_ass.ass")

    
    def add_subtitle_to_video(self, video_file, ass_file):
        video_text = [
            "ffmpeg",
            "-y",
            "-i", video_file,
            "-vf", f"subtitles={ass_file}",
            "-c:a", "copy",
            "output.mp4"
        ]
        process = subprocess.Popen(video_text, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,universal_newlines=True)


    # ADDS ANY TEXT STYLE TO THE TEXT
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    def text_styles(self, soup, stroke_size, stroke_color):
        text_styles = []
        paragraph = soup.find_all('p')
        span_elements = soup.find_all('span')

        if paragraph:
            for paragraph_element in paragraph:
                for content in paragraph_element.contents:
                    if isinstance(content, str):
                        written_text = content.strip()
                        text_styles.append(written_text)


        if span_elements:

            for span in span_elements:

                style_attr = span.get('style')
                style_and_name = style_attr.split(';')

                # Initialize variables to hold style modifications
                italic_str = underline_str = ""
                color_str = background_color_str = text_stroke = ""
                font_weight_str = font_size_str = ""
                font_family_str = ""

                for text in style_and_name:
                    if ':' in text:
                        style = text.split(':')[0].strip()
                        style_name = text.split(':')[1].strip().replace("'", '')

                        if stroke_size > 0:
                            stroke_color = stroke_color.replace('#', '')
                            red = int(stroke_color[0:2], 16)
                            green = int(stroke_color[2:4], 16)
                            blue = int(stroke_color[4:6], 16)
                            text_stroke = f"\\bord{stroke_size}\\3c&H{blue:02X}{green:02X}{red:02X}&"

                        # Modify text based on style
                        if style_name == 'italic':
                            italic_str = "{\\i1}"

                        elif style_name == 'underline':
                            underline_str = "{\\u1}"

                        elif style == 'color':
                            hex_color = style_name.replace('#', '')
                            red = int(hex_color[0:2], 16)
                            green = int(hex_color[2:4], 16)
                            blue = int(hex_color[4:6], 16)
                            color_str = f"\\c&H{blue:02X}{green:02X}{red:02X}&"

                        elif style == 'background-color' and stroke_size <= 0:
                            hex_color = style_name.replace('#', '')
                            red = int(hex_color[0:2], 16)
                            green = int(hex_color[2:4], 16)
                            blue = int(hex_color[4:6], 16)
                            background_color_str = f"\\rBackground\\bord1\\3c&H{blue:02X}{green:02X}{red:02X}&"

                        elif style == 'font-weight':
                            font_weight_str = "{\\b1}"

                        elif style == 'font-size':
                            font_size = style_name.replace('pt', '')
                            font_size_str = f"\\fs{font_size}"
                        
                        elif style == 'font-family':
                            font_family_str = f"\\fn{style_name}"

                        
                        # Combine all style modifications
                        text_style = "{" + text_stroke + background_color_str + color_str + italic_str + underline_str + font_size_str + font_family_str + font_weight_str + "}"  
                        text_with_styles = f"{text_style}{span.text.strip()}{{\\r}}"
            
                # Append modified text to the list
                text_styles.append(text_with_styles)

        return text_styles
    

    # Retrive the basic text style attributes
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    def retrieve_text_style(self, style_attr):
        style_and_name = style_attr.split(';')
        style_attributes = []
        
        for text in style_and_name:
            if ':' in text:
                style_name = text.split(':')[1].strip().replace("'", '')
                if 'pt' in style_name:
                    style_name = style_name.replace('pt', '')
                    style_attributes.append(style_name)
                    break
                
                style_attributes.append(style_name)
        
        return style_attributes
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Video Exporter")

        self.export_button = QPushButton("Export Video")
        self.export_button.clicked.connect(self.export_video)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.export_button)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def export_video(self):
        text_and_stroke = [("new_subtitle.html", "0", "0", 10, "#FFFFFF", "0:00:00.00", "0:00:05.00")]
        self.export_thread = videoExport(text_and_stroke, "other.mp4")
        self.export_thread.finished.connect(self.on_export_finished)
        self.export_thread.start()

    def on_export_finished(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Export Finished", "Video export completed!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


The negatives of doing this way is that if you have a text animation within your scene you will have to learn how to convert it to .ASS animation which should be possible, also if you have non text animations on your QGraphicsScene and want to export as an MP4 you will probably have to use multiprocessing to capture the scene, (there could be other ways). The text stroke is only applicable if you are able to retrieve it I'm unsure if there is a way the the basic QGraphicsTextItem but since I'm not using Qt's outline system but instead drawing my own I can grab it.
Some more information about the .ASS I found useful and the way I create my outline text:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78362730/22802649
https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/ffmpeg/subtitle/ass.html

I think the problem that you'll face with the current approach (UI screen capture to produce annotated video) is that you'll likely lose the original video resolution (say if its 1080p but displayed in 300x400 UI frame, then you'll end up with 300x400 video not 1080p).
A better approach IMO is to generate a text image (PNG) with transparent background in FFmpeg (or any other means) with the matching frame resolution (so 1080p in my example), and load each of such images onto the QGraphicScene as a QGraphicItem (which I presume can be dragged around to reposition).
This will get you the background video and a bunch of text images with their display times and position offsets. Then, FFmpeg can handle merging these files together.
To generate a text PNG, you can run
import subprocess as sp

video_size = [1920, 1080]
text = "hello world"
color = "black"
fontsize = 30
fontfile = "Freeserif.ttf"

textfile = "temp_01.png" # place it in a temp folder & increment

sp.run(
    [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-f", "lavfi",
        "-i", f"color=c={color}@0:size={video_size[0]}x{video_size[1]},format=rgba",
        "-vf", f'drawtext=fontsize={fontsize}:fontfile={fontfile}:text=\'{text}\':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2',
        "-update", "1", "-vframes", "1",
        "-y", # if needed to overwrite old
        textfile,
    ]
)

This script creates a PNG with "hello world" in the middle of the screen. Let's say we want to put this text between timestamps 1 and 2s of the video with user-defined offset of [-200px,100px] (towards the bottom-left corner).

text_start = 1
text_end = 2
text_xoff = -200
text_yoff = 100

videofile = "example.mp4"
outfile = "annotated.mp4"

sp.run(
    [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i", videofile,  # [0:v]
        "-i", textfile,  # [1:v]
        "-filter_complex", f"[0:v][1:v]overlay=x={text_xoff}:y={text_yoff}:enable='between(t,{text_start},{text_end})'[out]",
        "-map", "[out]",
        '-y', # again, if need to overwrite previous output
        outfile,
    ]
)

If you have multiple text images to overlay, you need to list all the text files as additional inputs (-i ...) and run overlay filters in cascade:
[0:v][1:v]overlay=...[out1];
[out1][2:v]overlay=...[out2];
...
[outN][N:v]overlay=...[out]

Obviously, you want t generate the filtergraph expression programmatically.
Here are the links to the filters used color, format, drawtext, overlay. Familiarize yourself with these filters and the filtergraph construction in general (see the top of the linked doc page), especially be aware of the character escaping. (hint: place the text in single quotes and escape single quotes in your overlay text)
Notes

if text is too long, it gets truncated off video frame
once you get this mechanism down, you can look into if the piped PNG data can be used by Qt. FFmpeg supports base64 encoding using the data protocol.
overlay filter supports the text image to move in time thus animatable, but displaying the animation on Qt would be a pain
I think there is a limitation on how long a subprocess command can be. So you may hit the limit with this approach, especially if you encode the png data.

I'm not familiar with Qt end of the business. So, I'll leave that to you.
Feel free to ask questions in the comment section.

I think since the text is being created to an image and then added to the video, I might as well just draw the text directly to the video? I'm unsure how I will maintain the format such as some characters in the QGraphicsTextItem text have different colours , boldness and e.t.c. However there is probably a way of doing it.

You can certainly go straight to baking the text on video, but I was under the impression that you want user to be able to position/format the text on UI. What I'm suggesting here is instead of let Qt render the text, render it with FFmpeg and display its result as floating images on canvas with the video as the backsplash, if this makes sense.

Something along this post. Then you can still move the text around in Qt. A new text image needs to be generated if user wants to change text format though.

I should've been more clear, the users must be able to changed the text format and position regularly (similar to a video editor) and creating a new image text every time they need to change something would be inefficient, I'm looking into what @musicamante suggested on optimizing it by using multiprocessing, however, thanks for the suggestion.

Gotcha. It may not be not as expensive as you may think. I'd suggest trying the image generation to see its speed before abandon this path. Good luck!
